# Google Analytics Event fire Before Pageview

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

What happen if a Google Analytics Event fires before a Google Analytics pageview?

I have some Landing Page Source attribution ( *not set* ) and i think that this firing issue could be the problem.

I have this problem because of an error in the dataLayer settings (an event fired before gtm.js inclusion).

Answer (score 1):

If you know what tag it is you can reconfigure it to fire normal. Also there is a "rule" in tag settings that you can set that specific tag to fire after/before any other tag so it may also be the problem.